# Multiple chi-square tests in R

Tags: r, stat, chi-squared, bonferroni

Imagine I have the following data:

| ID. | Drug1. | Drug2. | Drug3. | Drug4. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1. | 0. | 0. | 0. |
| 2. | 0. | 0. | 0. | 1. |
| 3. | 0. | 1. | 0. | 0. |
| 4. | 0. | 0. | 1. | 0. |
| 5. | 1. | 0. | 0. | 0. |

Where ID is the number given to each patient and each Drug variable is a binary variable where 1 indicates that patient had a certain condition on that drug and 0 indicates he/she didn't.

In order to compare the proportion of the rate of condition between drugs, I want to perform chi-sqauare tests like: Drug1 vs Drug2, Drug1 vs Drug3, Drug1 vs Drug4, Drug2 vs Drug3, Drug2 vs Drug4, etc.

How can I do this in R in one line of code?
Btw, is it necessary to implement correction for multiple comparisons (e.g., Bonferroni)?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mike I can do them one by one using chisq.test, but I wonder if I can do them all with one line of code. Btw I'm not sure if Bonferroni correction applies to these tests, and if yes, how I should apply it.

Comment: the bonferroni question really depends on how many tests you run/ how you are going to use the results its hard to answer without more info.

Comment: @Mike well forget about the bonferroni, how can I do the chi square tests?

Comment: the answer below is sufficient

Comment: @Mike yup, following its new edit, it looks good now. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a tidyverse approach using {dplyr}.
I first generate some data to run real tests with meaningful results.
Then we can use the `colnames` of `mydat` with `combn` to get all pairs of drugs. Then we can use `rowwise` and  `mutate` and apply `chisq.test()` to each row. Here we use the strings in `V1` and `V2` to subset the variables in `mydat`. Since we are in a `data.frame` we have to wrap the result in `list` if its a non-atomic vector. We can subset `chisq_test` with `$p.value` to get the p values.

```r
library(dplyr) 
set.seed(123)

mydat <- tibble(ID = 1:1000,
                Drug1 = round(rnorm(1000, 0.8, sd = 0.5)),
                Drug2 = round(rnorm(1000, 0.6, sd = 0.5), 0),
                Drug3 = round(rnorm(1000, 0.5, sd = 0.5), 0),
                Drug4 = round(rnorm(1000, 0.3, sd = 0.3), 0)
                ) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Drug"), ~ case_when(.x >0 ~ 0,
                                                 .x <1 ~ 1,
                                                 TRUE ~ .x))
  )

mydat %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  colnames() %>% 
  combn(2) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(chisq_test = list(
    table(mydat[[V1]], mydat[[V2]]) %>% chisq.test()
    ),
    chisq_pval = chisq_test$p.value
    )

#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   V1    V2    chisq_test chisq_pval
#>   <chr> <chr> <list>          <dbl>
#> 1 Drug1 Drug2 <htest>       0.00694
#> 2 Drug1 Drug3 <htest>       0.298  
#> 3 Drug1 Drug4 <htest>       0.926  
#> 4 Drug2 Drug3 <htest>       0.998  
#> 5 Drug2 Drug4 <htest>       0.574  
#> 6 Drug3 Drug4 <htest>       0.895
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Below is my old answer, which compares the distribution of `0` and `1` within each drug, which is not what the OP asked for, as @KU99 correctly pointed out in the comments.

```r
library(tibble) # for reading in your data

mydat <-
  tribble(~ID, ~Drug1,  ~Drug2, ~Drug3,  ~Drug4,
           1, 1,      0,      0,      0,  
           2, 0,      0,      0,      1,  
           3, 0,      1,      0,      0,  
           4, 0,      0,      1,      0,  
           5, 1,      0,      0,      0
  )

lapply(mydat[, -1], function(x) chisq.test(table(x)))

#> $Drug1
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  table(x)
#> X-squared = 0.2, df = 1, p-value = 0.6547
#> 
#> 
#> $Drug2
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  table(x)
#> X-squared = 1.8, df = 1, p-value = 0.1797
#> 
#> 
#> $Drug3
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  table(x)
#> X-squared = 1.8, df = 1, p-value = 0.1797
#> 
#> 
#> $Drug4
#> 
#>  Chi-squared test for given probabilities
#> 
#> data:  table(x)
#> X-squared = 1.8, df = 1, p-value = 0.1797
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot! one simple problem though, I already have data stored in variables Drug1, Drug2, etc. I don't want to define those variables again (there are actually thousands of data). So how can I simply do it on already stored data in variables?

Comment: This is not drug comparison. ie no comparison between drug 1vs drug 2 etc. You have not answered the question

Comment: @KU99: Thanks for pointing this out, I misunderstood the question and corrected my answer.

Comment: @AmirValizadeh: Please check out the update. I think this is more what you are looking for.